# Hoe can we use session of one python file in another python file?

Tags: python, sqlite, authentication, session, flask

I am trying to make login system in flask using sqlite3 and session. I have make `session['login']=True` in `login.py` file like this

```
from flask import render_template,Blueprint,request,session,flash,redirect,url_for
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
import sqlite3

log=Blueprint('login',__name__)
check_detail=Blueprint('check',__name__)

@log.route('/Login')
def login():

   return render_template('login.html')


@check_detail.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def check():
   email=request.form.get('mail')
   password=request.form.get('pass')
   try:
        conn=sqlite3.connect('user.db')
        c=conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""SELECT * FROM login WHERE email=:email""",
                 {
                     'email':email
                  })
        data=c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        if (check_password_hash(data[0][2],password)==True):
            session['login']=True
            return redirect(url_for('second.home'))
        else:
            flash("Incorrect Password")
            return render_template('login.html')
    except:

        flash("No such email is registered")
        return render_template('login.html')
```

and I try to clear that session in `logout.py` using `session.clear()` like this

```
from flask import render_template,session,Blueprint,redirect,url_for

loggedout=Blueprint('logout',__name__)

@loggedout.route('/Login')
def logout():
   session.clear()
   return render_template('login.html')
```

But it does not clear that session.

What should I do to clear that session of `login.py`?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions     this should help you

Comment: try `session.pop('login', None)`  , this should clear/remove the session

Comment: I have already tried it. But it didn't work out.